# insertion of a string in a binary tree

Tags: c

i need to create a program using c  (using binary tree) this program is required to save students names and ids and allow you to insert, delete, search and display names in preorder, inorder and post order and i wrote the code but it didn't work there is a problem in the insertion it takes only the id and it doesn't take the name and i want to know whats the problem with this code

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <string.h>


struct bin_tree
 {
int data;
char  name[100];
struct bin_tree * right, * left;
};
 typedef struct bin_tree node;

  void insert(node ** tree, int val, char  word[100])
{
node *temp = NULL;
if(!(*tree))
{
    temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = val;
    temp->data =  word;
    *tree = temp;
    return;
}

if(val < (*tree)->data)
{
    insert(&(*tree)->left, val,word);
}
else if(val > (*tree)->data)
{
    insert(&(*tree)->right, val,word);
}

 }


    struct tree *delet(struct bin_tree *ptr,int x)
 {
struct bin_tree *p1,*p2;
if(!ptr)
{
    printf("\n student not found ");
    return(ptr);
}
else
{
    if(ptr->data < x)
    {
        ptr->right = delet(ptr->right,x);

    }
    else if (ptr->data >x)
    {
        ptr->left=delet(ptr->left,x);
        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        if(ptr->data == x)
        {
            if(ptr->left == ptr->right)
            {
                free(ptr);
                return(NULL);
            }
            else if(ptr->left==NULL)
            {
                p1=ptr->right;
                free(ptr);
                return p1;
            }
            else if(ptr->right==NULL)
            {
                p1=ptr->left;
                free(ptr);
                return p1;
            }
            else
            {
                p1=ptr->right;
                p2=ptr->right;
                while(p1->left != NULL)
                    p1=p1->left;
                p1->left=ptr->left;
                free(ptr);
                return p2;
            }
        }
    }
}
return(ptr);
 }

 node* search(node ** tree, int val)
 {
if(!(*tree))
{
    return NULL;
}

if(val < (*tree)->data)
{
    search(&((*tree)->left), val);
}
else if(val > (*tree)->data)
{
    search(&((*tree)->right), val);
}
else if(val == (*tree)->data)
{
    return *tree;
}
}
void print_preorder(node * tree)
 {
    if (tree)
{
    printf("%d\n%s\n",tree->data,tree->name);
    print_preorder(tree->left);
    print_preorder(tree->right);
}

 }

  void print_inorder(node * tree)
 {
if (tree)
{
    print_inorder(tree->left);
    printf("%d\n%s\n",tree->data,tree->name);
    print_inorder(tree->right);
}
}

 void print_postorder(node * tree)
{
if (tree)
{
    print_postorder(tree->left);
    print_postorder(tree->right);
    printf("%d\n%s\n",tree->data,tree->name);
}
 }



 void main()
 {
node *root;
node *tmp;
int a,item_no,z,i=0;
char  x,b[100],c;

root=NULL;
while(x!='5')
{
    printf("\nmenu\n----\n1. insert\n2. delete\n3. search\n4. display\n5. end program     \n\n");

    printf("\nEnter the choice:");
    scanf("%s",&x);
    switch(x)
    {
    case '1':
    {
        printf("\nEnter the id: ");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("\nenter the name: ");
        while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && i < 100 )
        {
            b[ i++ ] = c;
        }
        b[ i ] = '\0';
        insert(&root,a,b[100]);
        break;
    }
    case '2':
    {
        printf("\n Enter the student id to be deleted : ");
        scanf(" %d",&item_no);
        root=delet(root,item_no);
        break;
    }
    case '3':
    {
        printf("\nEnter student id: ");
        scanf("%d",&z);
        tmp = search(&root, z);
        if (tmp)
        {
            printf("\nstudent id=%d\nstudent name: %s\n", tmp->data,tmp->name);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nData Not found.\n");
        }
    }
    case '4':
    {
        printf("Pre Order Display\n");
        print_preorder(root);

        printf("In Order Display\n");
        print_inorder(root);

        printf("Post Order Display\n");
        print_postorder(root);
    }
    case '\t':
    case '\n':
    case ' ':
    default :{
    printf("\nwrong entery!\n");
    break;
    }

    }


}

return 0;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Well first off. What doesn't work the way you expect it to? (and maybe add a better title to your question)

Answer (score 0):

Well lets look at your insert function.

```
void insert(node ** tree, int val, char  word[100])
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        temp->data =  word;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }
 ...
```

I assume the problem is that `temp->data = word`. My compiler (gcc) generates a warning `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`. word is a char array and data is an int. I assume you wanted `temp->name = word`.

As this doesn't compile without lots of warnings. I think you should try to get it to compile first as I assume there are other places that cause compilation errors or warnings too.

If you are using gcc add the flags `-Wall -Wextra` to show lots of warnings that might help fix bugs.

---

How about we look at where we call insert.

```
case '1':
{
    printf("\nEnter the id: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("\nenter the name: ");
    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && i < 100 )
    {
        b[ i++ ] = c;
    }
    b[ i ] = '\0';
    insert(&root,a,b[100]);
    break;
}
```

Here you are passing in b[100] as the word.

1. b is defined as `char b[100]` so calling b[100] is undefined behavior as you are accessing outside the array.
2. b[100] returns a char and you pass it in to a function that is looking for an array. You should call it a `insert(&root,a,b)`
3. Turn on compiler warning.

Comment: thanks you are really helping me in correcting my mistakes and to learn from it ... but the program still not working i changed temp->data to temp->name[100] and b[100] to b but there's still an error

Comment: @user2395710 `temp->name[100] = ...` is assigning something to 100 the hundredth position in the array. It should just be `temp->name`. I recommend getting a good book for c as this is really basic stuff.

Comment: it gives error when i write temp->name and this error is gone when i write temp->name[100]

Comment: @user2395710 sorry I'm not sure whats wrong. I haven't looked over your code enough to find all the problems. Nor do I know all the changes you have made.